# What is the glob2 module?

Tags: python, glob

```
import glob2
from datetime import datetime



filenames = glob2.glob("*.txt")
with open(datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S-%f")+".txt", 'w') as file:
    for filename in filenames:       
        with open(filename, "r") as f:
            file.write(f.read() + "\n")
```

I was working in python and came across this name glob, googled it and couldn't find any answer, what does glob do, why is it used for?

Comment: if it works, it scans all text files from curent dir and concatenate their contents on a big, dated file.

Comment: if you ask me, the flaw is that running this program again uses the output from prior execution since the extension & dir are the same for input & output

Comment: [`glob2`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/glob2) is an external library.

Comment: I am new to python i really dont have any idea about glob2,     filenames = glob2.glob("*.txt") what does the above code does..  can someone explain this line by line...

Comment: hmmm... I see someone is doing the python mega course.  ;)

Answer (score 4):

I also saw "glob2"-module used in a kaggle-notebook and researched my own answer in what is the difference to "glob".

All features of "[glob2](https://github.com/miracle2k/python-glob2/)" are in the current included "glob"-implementation of python.

So there is no reason to use "glob2" anymore.
As for what glob does in general, [BlueTomato](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4450090/bluetomato) already provided a nice link and description.

Comment: Is this still the case / is glob2 outdated?

Comment: The last version is from June 2019 ... I would go for the python-included "glob".

Comment: `glob2` handles `**` as recursive, while `glob` does not. Makes it harder to work with glob-strings. But `pathlib` handles that as well.

Answer (score 3):

from [glob docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html)

"The glob module finds all the pathnames matching a specified pattern(...)"

i skip the imports `import glob2` and
 `from datetime import datetime`

get all the filenames in the directory where filename is any and it is extension is text

```
filenames = glob2.glob("*.txt")
```

open new file which name is current datetime in the format as specified in the strftime and open it with write access as variable 'file'

```
with open(datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S-%f")+".txt", 'w') as file:
```

for each filenames in found files which names / paths are stored in filenames variable...

```
for filename in filenames:
```

with the filename open for read access as f:

```
with open(filename, "r") as f:
```

write all content from f into file and add \n to the end (\n = new line)

```
file.write(f.read() + "\n")
```